# How can I change the precision in the decimal field of CCK?

Tags: entities

I have a decimal field.  The field has a minimum precision of 10. Can I change this precision?  I need that the numbers allowed have the next format:  19.1, 20.3.  In other words that the number be  of  2 integers and one decimal.

I select one decimal in the configuration of the decimal field , however the field accepts big numbers.  How can I change this, the solution can be with form_alter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible via form alter however I would implement these verifications in a [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)  to check that your number is between 10 and 99.9 (2 decimals) and a precision of just one digit.
Put this code in a `custom.module`:

```php
function mymodule_nodeapi($node, $op, $a3, $a4) {
  if ($op == 'validate') {
    $number = $node->field_mynumber[0]['value'];
    if ($number < 10 || $number > 100) {
      form_set_error('field_mynumber', t('Please select a number between 10 and 99.9.'));
    }
    if (round($number, 1) != $number) {
      form_set_error('field_mynumber', t('Please select a number with a precision of 1 digit.'));
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you can also add a test on `$node->type` to restrict this on some of your content types.
PS: answer updated to use D6

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time.  Your idea is good but your option did not work to me.  

I replacement the "field_number" by my field in cck in the code but it doesn't work, what will it be my mistake?

 What's the meaning of "node->language"? I'm sorry for this question.

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you on Drupal 7 because `[$node->language]` is Drupal 7 specific, if you're on D6 you have to remove this part.

Comment: hello.  I put the next code:

function mymodule_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  $number = $node->field_mynumber[0]['value'];
  if ($number < 10 || $number > 100) {
    form_set_error('field_mynumber', t('Please select a number between 10 and 99.9.'));
  }
  if (round($number, 1) != $number) {
    form_set_error('field_mynumber', t('Please select a number with a precision of 1 digit.'));
  }
}

and it doesn't work.  I am working with Drupal 6.  I'm sorry, I forgot to put the version of drupal.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer, hook_node_validate is specific to D7.

Comment: Hello.  Very good.  This it works well for validate the numbers between 10 and 100 but it doesn't validate that the number only has one decimal.  Thanks very much.

Comment: What are the number you'd like to validate ? Is 12.34 valid or just 12.3 ? Give me a little more precision to update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I need numbers as 12.3.  Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer which was wrong for the precision part ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am going to review later and I'll give an answer.   
Is it correct this code?  if (if ((round($number, 1) - $number) != 0)) 

Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: Yes it is (at least with my tests).

Comment: I tested the code and shows error in the module.  If I delete an " if" doesn't show error but not validate.  Thanks for the idea.  It's a good idea your code.

Comment: Should be corrected, sorry about that.

Comment: If your number is for example `1.23` my code will display an error as `round(1.23, 1)` gives you 1.2 and this is different from `1.23` thus the error in the validation part.

Comment: yes to your opinion.  The problem is mine, I see that the != is not working, but I believe that your code is good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yeah, _node_validate is a flexible way. an alternative to a custom module, can be use a **Rules** module and integration with **Rules Forms support** module. Also will be useful use a more flexible CCK field, then, this will allow to validate whatever number with the model that you want.

.1. install the modules.

.2. then we need now is indicate to rules in what form must work. You must go to **Rules > Form events** and enable the option Enable event activation messages on forms. then go to the respective form and click in the **Activate events for.. (the name of the form)**

.3. go to rules and add a new rule and select in the **Event:** the respective event on which you want to evaluate this rule. (to this case **Rules Forms** modules will include the name of your form in the **Rules Forms** section on the **Event** select list.

.4. In a condition of rule add a **numeric comparison** (or whatever other condition that you want, for example a custom php code):

example with numeric comparison:

**field Number 1 (php code):** `$number= $form_state['values']['number'][0]['value']; if ($number < 10 || $number > 100) { echo 1; }`

**Field Comparison:** Equal to

**Field Number 2:** 1

.5. in the action option, of your rule, add an action like a form error message to warn about change the syntax of the number. in **Form element ID** add the ID of the field, for example field_color (you can review the name in the list of fields CCK of the content/node type).

.6. Create a new rule if is necessary, like `$number= $form_state['values']['number'][0]['value']; if (...) { echo 1; }` and add the respective error message.

do not forget enable the rule, to see working your rule!.

(I hope that this information be useful)

Comment: Hi.  Your idea it's works with rules.  I will take it this idea if with node_validation is not possible, because I have many forms for validate.

I am going to try to validate that the number of decimals is not bigger that one.

Thanks for your answer and your time.