# Webform rules: compare a form field to a user field

Tags: 7, users, webforms, rules

I am trying to create a rule that will update a user piece of info from a webform. 
The webform is a service request form and the field I want to update is a car license plate field, present both in user fields and webform fields. 
I installed the [Webform rules](http://drupal.org/node/1310226) module, which exposes the webform in the rules conditions but I cannot see anything changed. No webform or webform field appears in the conditions selections.
Does this module work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you can enable [Rules Forms support](http://drupal.org/project/rules_forms) Submodule of Rules. This submodule shows the correct name of your form (above each respective form) to be used with Rules.

Also, [see this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8941/how-can-i-change-the-precision-in-the-decimal-field-of-cck/8947#8947), is related with [Rules Forms support](http://drupal.org/project/rules_forms) submodule and other steps to make a comparision form fields with rules, I think that could be useful.

**Update:** This is the address to download the module [Rules Forms support](http://drupal.org/project/rules_forms) for Drupal 7 http://drupal.org/project/rules_forms

this is an screen shot in Drupal 7 about when is enabled rules for a specific webform:

[image: screen shot Drupal 7 actived rules for a specific webform]

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Have you actually tested it with the **Webforms** module?

Comment: hello @nikan, my experience is with Drupal 6, was updated the answer with information related with Drupal 7 (that seems have improvements).

Comment: This looks even better!

Comment: If the $user is not available, you could add a user specific condition to access the user variable.  For example: Condition -> User is blocked == FALSE.  This should bring the user variable into scope for use with rules.